# Unwanted rebuild in Makefile

Tags: makefile

What principles should be followed in order not to rebuild some object in *Makefile* every time?

I only know the most primitive case where we can split the compilation into several steps: creating object modules and linking them. But what to do in more difficult cases? Let's say I have a set of input files and expected output files to test. I want to make it so that only tests on files with wrong output or changed files are re-run.

```
TEST_INPUT_FILES = $(wildcard $(TEST_DIR)/, *in)
TEST_OUTPUT_FILES = $(wildcard $(TEST_DIR)/, *out)
```

The above shows how I create lists for each group of files. And in general, how can I be sure that when one file is changed, tests will be passed on this file? Any advice or literature on this topic will be useful, I couldn’t find the answer myself, because everyone disassembles only the banal assembly case

Answer (score 0):

Make creates files from other files using the shell and any program in the shell environment, should the target files not exist or be out of date.

What you'd do is have Make rules running the test with the tested program and any input files, including expected output, then create a test report file. If you want to rerun a failed test you'd remove (clean) the test report prior running the test.

```
# Make report from test program and inputs
$(REPORT): $(TEST) $(TEST_INPUT) $(TEST_EXPECTED_OUTPUT)
# Remove old report, if any
    rm -f $@
# Run test creating report on success
    $^
```

You can also do this by adding report to .DELETE_ON_ERROR: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Targets

Comment: This is a good answer.  At a higher level, make decides what to rebuild by comparing _modification times_ on _files_.  If you want to use make to decide what recipes to run and when to run them you must reduce your problem set to comparing modification times on files.  That means you need a file that represents the last time the recipe was run, to be the _target_, then a set of other files that represent when to consider the target to be outdated, as the _prerequisites_.